# POI : duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class

Tags: android, apache-poi

Android POI integration. I have done lots of search but did not find solution.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
```

My gradle

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.4@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.13'
```

I found this
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard/issues/9

[There is no solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954990/android-apache-poi-error)

[There is no solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942297/xmlbeans-jar-cant-be-signed-when-imported-from-custom-class)

[There is no solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203143/android-studio-build-transformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug-error)

I did not used any other apache lib. and not used google play service. still the same issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

There a some discussions about how to get POI working on Android, see e.g. http://blog.kondratev.pro/2015/08/reading-xlsx-on-android-4-and-hopefully.html

The blow specifically states

> [...] however it will not work straighforwardly because xmlbeans jar in maven is defective and contains duplicates of classes, [...] it is easier just to prepare jars once and put them into libs directory (as described above)

So you might need to do a few things to make it work or you can use the re-packaged project at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx

Comment: it's not multi dex issue... It's duplication of class file.. I have already used multi dex application

Comment: As the blog states the xmlbeans-jar that is usually downloaded contains duplicate classes which fails on Android, therefore you can either manually remove those duplicates or use the re-packaged ones that are provided in one of the github-projects